# MATLAB: Debugging Newton Raphson Method

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am trying to model a liquid level control and I am trying to solve an implicit equation using newton raphson method

```
t=(0:1:10);
x=[14 -4.32E-4 5.28E-4]; y=[14 7];
[t,x]=ode45(@PHandLiquidlevelmain,t,x) % returns x 

% For this time period t ,I have x as a 11X3 double array.
% And I am trying to access that array to calculate y

y=zeros(max(size(t)),2);

cv=8.75;
pk1=6.35;
pk2=10.25;


for l=1:1:1% For output Y(1)
   for k=1:1:11
      if l<2
         y(k,l)=y(k,l)+x(k,l);% Equation governed to calculate y(1)
      end
   end
end

for l=2:1:2
   for k=1:1:11

       if l<3

         syms z;
         format long;

         Equa_0=((x(k,l))+(10^(z-14))+((x(k,l+1))*((1+2*(10^(z-pk2)))/(1+(10^(pk1-z))+
                                                     (10^(z-pk2)))))-(10^(-z)))
         % using looping to get values of x(1,2)to x(t,2) and x(1,3) up to x(t,3)
         % and using it in Equa_0 to create t equations which are need to be
         % solved using Newton Raphson method

         %Newton  Raphson method      

         e = 1e-5;    % setting the tolerance value
         dx = e + 1;
         guess = 7;   % initially assumed value of z

         count = 0;   % setting counter to know the
                      % no of iterations taken                     
         p = zeros(1,1);
         while (abs(dx) > e) % initialising the iteration and 
                             % continue until the error is less than tolerance

             dx = (eval(Equa_0/(diff(Equa_0)))); % calculating dx, diff is used for 
                                                 % finding the differentiation of the  
                                                 % function
             guess = guess - dx;  % updating the value of x
             count = count + 1;   % incrementing the counter
             p(count) =guess;
             drawnow();
             plot(abs(p),'r','linewidth',3);
             grid;
             if (count > 300)

                 fprintf('Error...! Solution not converging !!! \n');  % printing the 
                                                                       % error message
                 break;
             end
         end
         if (count < 300)
             fprintf('The solution = ');  %printing the result
             y(k,l)=y(k,l)+guess;% y(1,1) to y(t,1) is calculated
             fprintf('\nNumber of iteration taken = %d\n',count);
         end
      end
  end
end
y
```

The outputs are:

```
 t =

 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10


x =

14.0000   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0001   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0001   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0002   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0002   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0003   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0003   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0003   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0004   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0004   -0.0004    0.0005
14.0005   -0.0004    0.0005


Equa_0 =

 10^(z - 14) - 1/10^z + (33*(2*10^(z - 41/4) + 1))/(62500*(10^(z - 41/4) + 10^(127/20 -   
 z) + 1)) - 27/62500
```

And the following error occured:

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.  

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in PHmain (line 55)
             p(count) =guess;
```

I tried `vpa` function but to no avail. The `Equa_0` accepts the `x` values but seem to create a different sort of expression.

Comment: MATLAB is useful for numerical analysis (obviously). Define the equation you're operating on as a function - either in its own function file or in an anonymous function. Do the same for the derivative function (either find the analytical solution yourself or differentiate numerically). Avoid using the Symbolic Math toolbox for your operation. It looks like you're only using it to find the derivative of `Equa_0`, but it should be easy to do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One, you specify `guess` and manipulate it, but don't push it into Equa_0. You need to explicitly say `z = guess;` during each iteration before you calculate `dx` in the loop.

Two, in general, you shouldn't use the symbolic toolbox for this. If x is constant, use anonymous functions (this will require rewriting some of your code):

```
Equa_0=@(z) ((x(k,l))+(10^(z-14))+((x(k,l+1))*((1+2*(10^(z-pk2)))/(1+(10^(pk1-z))+ (10^(z-pk2)))))-(10^(-z)));
```

EDIT:
I should note that you still have other things to fix in your code, but I'll leave that part for you to figure out.